# Primitive matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is this definition for primitive matrices correct?

A square matrix $P \geqslant 0$ is called primitive if there exists a power $k$ such that $P^k > 0,$ that is, there exists a $k$ such that for all ${ij},$ the entries $ij$ are positive.

I read it in the Internet but it was not referenced.

Comment: This is not a real question. *What* do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know the definition of primitive matrices?

Comment: I've reformatted the question what do you think of it now?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron–Frobenius_theorem#Classification_of_matrices) uses the definition you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horn and Johnson agrees. Could also define as nonnegative matrix that is irreducible and has just one eigenvalue of maximum modulus.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me.